# Переопределение названия столбца с помощью аннотации entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, аннотации, codefirst

изучаю Entity framework Code First, у меня появилась проблема - При выводе таблицы в datagrid кроме столбцов назначенных в разметке выводятся так же столбцы определённые внутри кода, я решил переименовать их с помощью аннотаций, но при выводе всё так же выводятся старые имена, а при попытке вывести данные в самой бд вызывается исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при удалении аннотаций названия колонок ошибка исчезает. Код ReceiptInvoice:

```
 public class ReceiptInvoice 
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id приход")]
    public int Receiptid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Дата")]
    public DateTime DateOfArrivalReceipt { get; set; }
    [MinLength(0)]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Название Инвентаря")]
    public string NameOfInventoryReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Номер Инвентаря")]
    public int InventoryNumberReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Количество Инвентаря")]
    public int InventoryQuantityReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Id Сотрудника")]
    public int EmployeeIdReceipt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Column("Id Склада")]
    public int WarehouseIdReceipt { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне поступить чтобы вывести данные в таком виде, как я хочу?

Код вывода данных:

```
    public partial class EmployeeIncome : Page
{
    public EmployeeIncome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (CompanyDataContext db = new CompanyDataContext())
        {
            gridDataIncome.ItemsSource = db.ReceiptInvoices.ToList();

        }
    }


    private void CreateIncome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (CompanyDataContext db = new CompanyDataContext())
        {
            ReceiptInvoice receipt = new ReceiptInvoice();
            receipt.DateOfArrivalReceipt = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxDateOfArrial.Text);
            receipt.EmployeeIdReceipt = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxEmployeeId.Text);
            receipt.NameOfInventoryReceipt = TextBoxNameOfInventory.Text;
            receipt.InventoryQuantityReceipt = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInventoryQuantity.Text);
            receipt.InventoryNumberReceipt = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInventoryNumber.Text);
            receipt.WarehouseIdReceipt = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxWarehouseId.Text);
            //сделать обработку ошибок
            db.ReceiptInvoices.Add(receipt);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

    }
}
```

Код разметки:

```
<Page x:Class="Учёт_инвентаря_на_складах_предприятия.Views.EmployeeIncome"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Учёт_инвентаря_на_складах_предприятия.Views"
  mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="EmployeeIncome" Height="500">

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="gridDataIncome" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= receipt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="366" Margin="215,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="575">
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,590,0" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="Дата" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxDateOfArrial" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Label Content="№Инвентаря" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxInventoryNumber" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Label Content="Количество" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxInventoryQuantity" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Label Content="ID склада" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxWarehouseId" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Label Content="ID сотрудника" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxEmployeeId" Height="27" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Label Content="Название инвентаря" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxNameOfInventory" Height="27" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="CreateIncome" Content="Создать" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="668,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" Height="44" FontWeight="Bold" Click="CreateIncome_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут два варианта:
1. Ставишь атрибут в модели

```
[Key]
[Display(Name("Id приход")]
public int Receiptid { get; set; }
```

2. В разметке явно указываешь нужные столбцы

   ```
   <DataGrid.Columns>
   ```